# How to read UMat from a file in opencv 3.0 Beta?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencl

I want to use `UMat` so my code can be run on both GPU and CPU using OpenCL (OpenCV 3.0.0 Beta).

but I can not find a way to read an image file into a `UMat` or convert a `Mat` to `UMat`.

How can I read an image into a `UMat`?

Answer (score 17):

Sample for `Mat` to `UMat` conversion is below. Coudlnt' find documentation for this. So only option was to read the [source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L676).

```
UMat img = imread( "lena.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR  ).getUMat( ACCESS_READ );
```

Different access flags as in [source](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L59) are

```
ACCESS_READ, ACCESS_WRITE, ACCESS_RW, ACCESS_FAST
```

For undestanding `UMat` usage, a complete sample for face detection is available  [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/3.0-ocl-tp2/samples/cpp/ufacedetect.cpp). Also note that documentation still refers to older flags as `imread` second parameter. You might need to use newer flags as in your OpenCV header file.

Comment: There's some documentation [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ad3b86ff70d06f7e567e51d8d215c85cd), but it's indeed still pretty cryptic...

Answer (score 3):

What works for me is...

```
cv::UMat image;
cv::imread("image.jpeg", 1).copyTo(image);
```

This is using the latest opencv 3.2

Answer (score 1):

For covert I use `Uimage.copyTo(image)` or `image=Uimage.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ)` but last in some cases generate problem with reassign data.

If you want ti use `UMat` globally for all, may attend that present some limitation with use `UMat`. And may be better have reserve method with `Mat` if operation with `UMat` have access violation error.

```
clearReadyResultImage();
qDebug()<<"vpOpenCV::blurImage, try GPU cv::blur";
try{
   cv::blur(Uimage, UresultImage, cv::Size(ksize, ksize));
   UresultImageReady=!UresultImage.empty();
}
catch (cv::Exception& ex) {
     qWarning()<<"vpOpenCV::blurImage error"<<ex.what();
}
if (!UresultImageReady) {
     checkReadyImage();
     qDebug()<<"vpOpenCV::blurImage, try CPU cv::blur";
     try{
         cv::blur(image, resultImage, cv::Size(ksize, ksize));
         resultImageReady=!resultImage.empty();
     }
     catch (cv::Exception& ex) {
         qWarning()<<"vpOpenCV::blurImage error"<<ex.what();
     }
}

...

void checkReadyImage(){
     if (!imageReady && UimageReady){
         Uimage.copyTo(image);
         imageReady=!image.empty();
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain more why access violation error happens when using the .getMat() method?

Answer (score 0):

**Note that what I am describing here is NOT a correct answer!**

According to [this presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1qoa29N_B-s297-fp0-b3rBirvpzJQp8dCtllLQ4DVCY/present#slide=id.p25) (apparently an official one from [itseez](http://itseez.com/OpenCV/)) the correct way to load an image from file directly into a `cv::UMat` should be the following:

```
UMat img;
imread( "lena.jpg", -1, img); // -1 => CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED (colourwise)
```

However, this is not part of OpenCV 3 interface, so you should really use [Kiran's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27530966/2436175).

Answer (score -2):

You can convert (copy the underlying data) cv::Mat to cv::UMat and vice versa by using `copyTo` method.

Here is the sample code, that uses `cv::UMat`:

```
//VideoCapture tCapturer("2.avi"); // source is set to be the clip
VideoCapture tCapturer(0); // source is set to be the camera
UMat tUFrame;

if (!tCapturer.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Could not open video file!" << endl;
    getchar();
    return -1;
}
else
{
    cout << "Video file has been opened successfully!" << endl;
    getchar();
}

namedWindow("video", 1);

while (true)
{
    if (!tClip.read(tUFrame)) // get a new frame from camera
    {
        break;
    }

    Mat tRegularFrame;
    tUFrame.copyTo(tRegularFrame);

    imshow("video", tRegularFrame);

    if (waitKey(30) >= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```